# cannot get Julius to run properly

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this error message:

#### read waveform input

Stat: adin_oss: device name = /dev/dsp (application default)
Error: adin_oss: failed to open /dev/dsp
failed to begin input stream
Everything seems to be working until it reads the mic, then error.  It is in the Rear input of the desktop.  It cannot open it.  I tried the voice recorder program and it inputs and outputs fine. What do I do now??

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11563/cannot-get-julius-to-run-properly/) by [MovieMaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/1184/moviemaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-16

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-10-16**:
What does this have to do with ROS? This seems more appropriate for a Julius mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to run the command with padsp, like this:
$ padsp julius...

---

Originally posted by [smerino](https://answers.ros.org/users/675/smerino/) with karma: 108 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0